# background color is changing once we click cursor inside textfield

Tags: html, css

once we click cursor inside textfield , background color is changing.

Before :

[image]

once we click cursor inside textfield :

[image]

but i want to keep the same color after click cursor inside textfield.

**css**

```
input.input-text, select, textarea {
    font: /*BEGIN:general_font*/12px/1.35 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif/*END:general_font*/;
    padding: 2px 8px !important;
    border: 1px solid /*BEGIN:body_line1*/#dcdcdc/*END:body_line1*/;
    color: /*BEGIN:body_text_color3*/#a0a0a0/*END:body_text_color3*/;
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 29px;
    width: 80%;
}

input, select, textarea, button {
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

**phtml**

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="s" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__('Search by product name') ?>' 
value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('s')?>"/>
```

Comment: Something else is doing the changing. Look around for CSS affecting your `input`s.

Comment: Maybe check if the `:focus` value is changed somewhere :  https://jsfiddle.net/5ux42fb6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this media query in your code and it works :)

```
@media (min-width: 0)
:focus {
     background: none; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: can you please tell file name where this codee is present ?

Comment: I add a screenshot, seems to be line 40 of a CSS file

Comment: can you please help me to decrease the space between 4 textsfields.

Comment: can you please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269248/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your CSS,

CSS,

```
input:focus { background : none; }
```

To decrease or increase spacing between your input's use margin : 10px 0px;

CSS,

```
input.input-text, select, textarea {
font: /*BEGIN:general_font*/12px/1.35 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif/*END:general_font*/;
padding: 2px 8px !important;
border: 1px solid /*BEGIN:body_line1*/#dcdcdc/*END:body_line1*/;
color: /*BEGIN:body_text_color3*/#a0a0a0/*END:body_text_color3*/;
height: 29px;
line-height: 29px;
width: 80%;
**margin:10px 0px;**
```

}

Comment: can you please help me to decrease the space between 4 textfields [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/)